# Array of case class as parameter T

Tags: scala

If I have these 2 or N `case class`es as follows:

```
case class dbep1 (a1:String, b1:String, ts1: Integer)
case class dbep2 (a2:String, b2:String, ts2: Integer)

var dbep1D = new ArrayBuffer[dbep1]()   
dbep1D = ArrayBuffer(dbep1("Mark", "Hamlin", 2), dbep1("Kumar", "XYZ", 3), dbep1("Tom", "Poolsoft", 4)) 
var dbep2D = new ArrayBuffer[dbep2]()   
dbep2D = ArrayBuffer(dbep2("Pjotr", "Hamming", 4), dbep2("Kumar", "ABNC", 7), dbep2("Tom", "Gregory", 3))
```

How can I write a def that accepts both of these as an array of T, like so:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
def printArray[a: ArrayBuffer[T]]() = {
// do anything with ArrayBuffer[T] 
  println(a)
}
```

Clearly not correct, just passing a single variable case class will work as per below:

```
def doSomeThing[T]() = {
// ...
}
case class SomeClassA(id: UUID, time: Date)
doSomeThing[SomeClassA]()
```

But what if I want an ArrayBuffer of a give case class as input?

May be just not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doSomeThing` function does not take an argument. It takes a generic argument but no actual values, and with no arguments at all (not even an implicit `ClassTag`), there's absolutely nothing you can do with it.

I'll assume you meant

```
def doSomeThing[T](arg: T) = {
  // ...
}
```

If you want your function to take an arbitrary array buffer instead, you don't replace the thing *inside* brackets; that's still a free variable. You change the argument type.

```
def printArray[T](arg: ArrayBuffer[T]) = {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: OK, I need to digest this and try out. Confusing as you do not reference def printArray. I will see if I understand - btw I am sure you are correct.

Comment: Right, I've edited it now. My bad. I just used `doSomeThing` as the placeholder in both cases. My intention was that the second function be your `printArray`.

Comment: OK, great stuff. Works. OK2, I think I have a few clues but I could not find this from tutorials etc. Also, the  def doSomeThing[T] did work. You beaut.